# Power Query - Get Data from AnalysisServices (Cube) - Filter with User-Function result

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have the following problem. I'm getting Data (Excel 365 - Power Query) from a Cube with "Get Data from Analysis Services". -> Selling Qty an Values for filtered years by week.

Every thing is fine if I use Filter, updatetime ca. 3-4 seconds:

```
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each 
        (Cube.AttributeMemberId([#"Date.Year (4-4-5)"]) = "[Date].[Year 4-4-5].&["&
         Number.ToText(2019) &"]" meta 
         [DisplayName = Number.ToText(2019)] 

         or Cube.AttributeMemberId([#"Date.Year (4-4-5)"]) = "[Date].[Year 4-4-5].&["&
         Number.ToText(2020) &"]" meta 
         [DisplayName = Number.ToText(2020)] 
         )
```

Now I like to do that dynamic, so that I can get the years from a cell in excel. I use the following M-Function "fktGetNamedCellValue" for this:

```
let
    Source = (FieldInput as text) => 

    let Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=FieldInput]}[Content], 
    Inhalt = Number.From(Quelle{0}[Column1])

in  Inhalt
in  Source
```

I replaced the years in the Filter-Step with the function.
The cells are named "cell_Prev_Year" and "cell_Plan_Year"
The cells in Excel formated as Numbers (and there are only Numbers in it)
The updatetime now -> endless!!!

```
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each 
        (Cube.AttributeMemberId([#"Date.Year (4-4-5)"]) = "[Date].[Year 4-4-5].&["&
         Number.ToText(fktGetNamedCellValue("cell_Prev_Year") &"]" meta 
         [DisplayName = Number.ToText(fktGetNamedCellValue("cell_Prev_Year"))] 

         or Cube.AttributeMemberId([#"Date.Year (4-4-5)"]) = "[Date].[Year 4-4-5].&["&
         Number.ToText(fktGetNamedCellValue("cell_Plan_Year")) &"]" meta 
         [DisplayName = Number.ToText(fktGetNamedCellValue("cell_Plan_Year"))] 
         )
```

If I use a "normal" parameter with the value "2019" or "2020" everything is fine. 
Only if I use the fktGetNamedCellValue it will not run correctly.

I`ed Trim an Clean the result. Formated it as Text and Number... nothing helped.

I have to use userfriendly Parameter (not set in Power Query) for this, so I hope for some help :)

Best Regards
Chris

(PS: I hope u understand my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows.

Since it is not an good idea to use an user-function as parameter to get data from an cube. I think this method disables query-folding or is called a lot of times in the process, I decided to use an power-query parameter.

I change this Parameter with vba by checking the worksheet_change event and calling this sub:

```
Sub refresh_Parameter(ParameterName As String, ParameterValue As Variant)

Dim strOldFormula As String
Dim strParametersMeta As String

strOldFormula = ThisWorkbook.Queries(ParameterName).Formula
strParametersMeta = Mid(strOldFormula, InStr(1, strOldFormula, "meta"), Len(strOldFormula))

    ThisWorkbook.Queries(ParameterName).Formula = ParameterValue & " " & strParametersMeta

Debug.Print strOldFormula
Debug.Print strParametersMeta

End Sub
```

The parameters for the sub arte the PARAMETER Name in PowerQuery and the VALUE which should be set. For this the sub extracts the meta-data from the query-formula and combines it with the new Value.

Maybe someone needs this :)

Best regards chris